# sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string, ruby, linux

Tags: ruby

I need to run two java compilers in ruby in linux. My code is:

```
system("java  -Xmx2g -cp .:mul.jar:weka.jar:TrainTest1 -arff fileinput.arff -xml NILM.xml -K #{parameter1} -name c_#{parameter2}_ G_#{parametere3} -class \"-C #{parameter2} -L 0.0010 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0
-V 10 -W 1 -K \"weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel -C 250007 -G #{parametere3}  \"\\")
```

I'm running `Weka` and `Mulan` libraries. I have the error `sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

Comment: your string ends with `\"\"`, is that intentional?

Comment: Hm, the error message says it all...

Comment: Why oh why does anyone use the single argument version of [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) when there is a sane and much safer multi-argument version? Sloppy use of the single argument version of `system` is the root cause of numerous security problems.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 quotes in your command line (unbalanced), i would imagine that you want 4 (or some other even number).

Comment: Already I can run it in windows with small changes , "/" dont make problem in windows and if I change them, will see error there, the problem is in linux.